# In Perl how can I read a file of unknown length into multiple hashes to be stored in an array for later use?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a config file that looks a bit like this:

```
add
    1
    2
concatenate
    foo
    bar
    blat
```

What I'm trying to do is turn this into hashes like `%hash = (name=>"add", args=> [1,2])` etc, and push the hash references into a single array.  Looping through the file and creating each hash seems straightforward enough, except I get stuck when it comes to naming these hashes to push their references into the array.  The config file is going to change all the time and have a variable number of different name/arg combinations to store.  Is there a way to iterate through hash names so I can push them into an array one at a time?

So far it looks like this:

```
my %temphash = (name=>'add', args=>[1,2]);  

push (@array, \%temphash);
```

Can I make that `%temphash` into something generated on the fly and push it before moving on to the next one?

Edit: Context

The plan is to use those 'name' keys to call subroutines.  So something like this could work:

```
my %subhash = (add=>\&addNumbers, concatenate=>\&concat);
```

Except the list of subroutines I'm going to need to call are in the config file and I won't know what they are until I start reading from it.  Even if I include the names of the subroutines right there in the config file, how do I iterate through them and add them as elements to that hash?

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Perhaps you are looking for `$temphash{$key} => [1,2];` where `$key = 'add'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can simply use curly brackets to make an anonymous hash:

```
push @array, { name => 'add', args => [1,2] };
```

You can create the same effect by utilising the lexical scope of the `my` declaration. E.g.:

```
my @array;
while ( ... ) {
    ...
    my %hash = ( ... );
    push @array, \%hash;
}
```

Comment: Rookie question: if %hash is only scoped to that loop can I still iterate through the elements in that array elsewhere?  I've never made an anonymous hash.  Sounds subversive.

Comment: The data will stay stored in the array, the reference will still point to the same address in memory. However, the name space referece (e.g. `%hash`) will be destroyed. Anonymous hashes/arrays are very good ways to solve these "throwaway variable" situations.

Comment: Ok, one more question to tack on.  I'm using this array to do something like this: `foreach(@array){print "Yo\n";}` but it ends up running that block once for each hash value stored (names and args), not once for each hash.  Does this have something to do with the hashes being anonymous or is there something more basic that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're asking, then you can write:

```
push @array, { name=>'add', args=>[1,2] };
```

where `{ ... }` is a reference to an anonymous hash.

That said, I'm a bit surprised that you want an array of hashes, when each hash has just a `name` and `args`. Why not have a single hash mapping from names to args? :

```
%array = ( add => [ 1, 2 ], concatenate => [ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ] );
```

Comment: Using a single hash for a dynamic file may overwrite identical keys that appear in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do what you need

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data_file' or die $!;

my $item;
my @data;

while (<$fh>) {
  chomp;
  next unless /^(\s*)(.+?)\s*$/;
  if ($1) {
    push @{ $item->{args} }, $2;
  }
  else {
    push @data, $item if $item;
    $item = { name => $2, args => [] };
  }
}
push @data, $item if $item;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;
```

**output**

```
[
  { args => [1, 2], name => "add" },
  { args => ["foo", "bar", "blat"], name => "concatenate" },
]
```